# How to expose Kubernetes DNS externally

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible for an external DNS server to resolve against the K8s cluster DNS? I want to have applications residing outside of the cluster be able to resolve the container DNS names?

Answer (score 7):

It's possible, there's a good article proving the concept: https://blog.heptio.com/configuring-your-linux-host-to-resolve-a-local-kubernetes-clusters-service-urls-a8c7bdb212a7

However, I agree with Dan that exposing via service + ingress/ELB + external-dns is a common way to solve this. And for dev purposes I use https://github.com/txn2/kubefwd which also hacks name resolution.

Answer (score 4):

Although it may be possible to expose coredns and thus forward requests to kubernetes, the typical approach I've taken, in aws, is to use the [external-dns controller](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/README.md).

This will sync services and ingresses with provides like aws. It comes with some caveats, but I've used it successfully in prod environments.

Answer (score 2):

coredns will return cluster internal IP addresses that are normally unreachable from outside the cluster. The correct answer is the deleted by MichaelK suggesting to use coredns addon k8s_external https://coredns.io/plugins/k8s_external/ .

k8s_external is already part of coredns. Just edit with
`kubectl -n kube-system edit configmap coredns` and add k8s_external after kubernetes directive per docs.

```
   kubernetes cluster.local
   k8s_external example.org
```

k8s_gateway also handles dns for ingress resources

- https://coredns.io/explugins/k8s_gateway/
- https://github.com/ori-edge/k8s_gateway (includes helm chart)

You'll also want something like metallb or rancher/klipper-lb handling services with `type: LoadBalancer` as k8s_gateway won't resolve NodePort services.

MichaelK is the author of k8s_gateway not sure why his reply is deleted by moderator.

Comment: This assumes that you are resolving internal cluster resources, but what if someone in a small shop or some other IoT kind of situation wants to have CoreDNS be a DNS server for stuff inside but ALSO outside the k8s cluster (e.g. a network DNS server)

Comment: k8s_gateway will return external IPs from service or ingress `status.loadbalancer` field. Same behaviour as external-dns mostly.

Comment: @MorganChristiansson To answer your question about why MichaelK's answer was deleted: I think it's because answers are supposed to be self-contained and his answer was basically just a link to his blog. It would probably have been fine if he would have provided a summary in the answer, with the link offering more details. Still does seem very discouraging to just delete someone's answer like that, rather than giving feedback on how to improve it.

Answer (score 1):

I've never done that, but technically this should be possible by exposing kube-dns service as NodePort. Then you should configure your external DNS server to forward queries for Kube DNS zone "cluster.local" (or any other you have in Kube) to kube-dns address and port.

In Bind that can be done like that:

```
zone "cluster.local" {
 type forward;
 forward only;
 forwarders{ ANY_NODE_IP port NODEPORT_PORT; };
};
```