# DNS server in kubernetes for translate LAN hosts

Tags: kubernetes, coredns

I am using a baremetal cluster of 1 master and 2 nodes on premise in my home lab with istio, metallb and calico.

I want to create a DNS server in kubernetes that translates IPs for the hosts on the LAN.

Is it possible to use the coreDNS already installed in k8s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible but there are some points to consider when doing that. Most of them are described in the Stackoverflow answer below:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Questions: How to expose Kubernetes DNS externally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834721/how-to-expose-kubernetes-dns-externally)*

For example: The DNS server would be resolving the queries that are internal to the Kubernetes cluster (like `nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local`).

---

I've included the example on how you can expose your `CoreDNS` to external sources and add a `Service` that would be pointing to some IP address

Steps:

- Modify the `CoreDNS` `Service` to be available outside.
- Modify the `configMap` of your `CoreDNS` accordingly to:

  - *[CoreDNS.io: Plugins: K8s_external](https://coredns.io/plugins/k8s_external/)*
- Create a `Service` that is pointing to external device.
- Test

---

#### Modify the `CoreDNS` `Service` to be available outside.

As you are new to Kubernetes you are probably aware on how `Services` work and which can be made available outside. You will need to change your `CoreDNS` `Service` from `ClusterIP` to either `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` (I'd reckon `LoadBalancer` would be a better idea considering the `metallb` is used and you will access the `DNS` server on a port: `53`)

- `$ kubectl edit --namespace=kube-system service/coredns`  (or `kube-dns`)

> A side note!
>
> `CoreDNS` is using `TCP` and `UDP` simultaneously, it could be an issue when creating a `LoadBalancer`. Here you can find more information on it:
>
> - [Metallb.universe.tf: Usage](https://metallb.universe.tf/usage/) (at the bottom)

---

#### Modify the `configMap` of your `CoreDNS`

If you would like to resolve domain like for example: `example.org` you will need to edit the `configMap` of `CoreDNS` in a following way:

- `$ kubectl edit configmap --namespace=kube-system coredns`

Add the line to the `Corefile`:

```
        k8s_external example.org
```

> This plugin allows an additional zone to resolve the external IP address(es) of a Kubernetes service. This plugin is only useful if the kubernetes plugin is also loaded.
>
> The plugin uses an external zone to resolve in-cluster IP addresses. It only handles queries for A, AAAA and SRV records; all others result in NODATA responses. To make it a proper DNS zone, it handles SOA and NS queries for the apex of the zone.
>
> -- *[CoreDNS.io: Plugins: K8s_external](https://coredns.io/plugins/k8s_external/)*

---

#### Create a `Service` that is pointing to external device.

Following on the link that I've included, you can now create a `Service` that will point to an IP address:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: test
 namespace: default
spec:
 clusterIP: None
 externalIPs:
 - 192.168.200.123
 type: ClusterIP
```

---

#### Test

I've used `minikube` with `--driver=docker` (with `NodePort`) but I'd reckon your can use the `ExternalIP` of your `LoadBalancer` to check it:

- `dig @192.168.49.2 test.default.example.org -p 32261 +short`

```sh
192.168.200.123
```

where:

- `@192.168.49.2` - IP address of `minikube`
- `test.default.example.org` - service-name.namespace.k8s_external_domain
- `-p 32261` - `NodePort` port
- `+short` - to limit the output

---

Additional resources:

- *[Linux.die.net: Man: Dig](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig)*

Comment: How I can add A, CNAME... records? Like test.example.com

Comment: @rbr86 the plugin that I've included in the question states on his documentation page that: `It only handles queries for A, AAAA and SRV records; all others result in NODATA responses.`.