Azure Kubernetes with Azure VPN to access pods on cluster hostname
I have an Azure Kubernetes cluster running with two Ubuntu containers named:

ubuntu-1
ubuntu-2
Each container has a Service of type ClusterIP.

I would like to be able to ping or communicate with these containers using their internal DNS hostnames, such as:
ubuntu-1.default.svc.cluster.local
ubuntu-2.default.svc.cluster.local
To achieve this, I created a Virtual Network Gateway in the same virtual network as the cluster. I am able to connect to the VPN client; however, when I attempt to run:
ping ubuntu-1.default.svc.cluster.local
I receive the following error:
ping: ubuntu-1.default.svc.cluster.local: Name or service not known
As a test, i tried to add the service internal ip and the hostname to my host file. But when i ping, i get back this:
--- ubuntu-1.default.svc.cluster.local ping statistics --- 5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4140ms
i know that updating the host file with the dns hostname and ip is not practical at all because those ips can change any moment.
How can I resolve this issue to successfully ping the internal DNS hostnames of the containers just by connecting successfully to my vpn?
Thank you so much for any guidance or help. And please if you have any further question and need my code sample or configuration, dont hesitate to ask
UPDATE:
I created the private DNS zone and attached it to the virtual network. in the dns zone nameservers i can see the internal ip of the virtual machine and while canneted to the Azure VPN client i am able to ping the vm. Now i tried to configure the coredns configmap. I faced an issue here to modify directly the coredns configmap as as soon as i save the new configuration, aks rolls back to the default one. So i modified the coredns-custom to override the Corefile as follow:
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: coredns-custom
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  Corefile.override: |
    .:53 {
      forward . <vnet resolver ip> {
        cache 30
        loop
        reload
        loadbalance
      }
    }


According to microsoft documentations, this should be by default my vnet ip. So if my vnet subnet is, for example 10.10.10.10 the resolver should be 10.10.10.4.
So i put this resolved in my configmap. the changes gets applied but i am still not able to ping the internal hostname of the pods.

If I understand correctly, you want to use the Kubernetes internal DNS from your computer to resolve containers' hostnames on this cluster. I found a similar post talking about that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55834721/how-to-expose-kubernetes-dns-externally

@FlorianVuillemot yes but only when i am connected to azure vpn, being part of the same network. So if i wanna test an internal api, i dont have to use a LoadBalancer to assign an ip or create a certificate etc. This way the pod can stay internal and i can connect to the vpn to test

So far you have created a VNET and subnet, AKS, inside AKS deployed 2 Ubuntu Pods and Services, created a Public IP for the VNETGateway , create the VNETGateway. When you say "I am able to connect to the VPN client" means VPN Client configuration created and downloaded?

@Arko Sorry if i wasnt clear on this. YEs i mean setting the p2s connection, download the client and use it to connect.

So then you have to set up DNS frwrding. Create and link your private DNS zone to your VNet. Edit the CoreDNS ConfigMap of your aks and add forwarding Rule in CoreDNS Configuration. forward . <azure-dns-resolver-ip>       cache 30       loop       reload       loadbalance and here put IP of the DNS Resolver. Once done, update VNet DNS settings, connect to VPN and check once again by pinging  ubuntu-1 and 2

@Arko Thank you for the guideline on this. i did create a private dns zone and attached it to my vnet and i am able to ping my vms, but when i try to modify the coredns configmap, as soon as i save the changes, aks rollsback to the default values. i am doing something wrong here?

Just updated my post with the latest changes
